# How to make mPDF 6.1 work with PHP 7.1.5

Tags: mpdf, php-7.1

Developed on on a WAMP stack with PHP 5.6, then transferred to LAMP 7.1.5
Everything is working OK except for mPDF 6.1.0 which is giving the following:

```
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /var/sites/s/example.com/php_libs/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 30648

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /var/sites/s/example.com/php_libs/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 17074

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /var/sites/s/example.com/php_libs/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 17075

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /var/sites/s/example.com/php_libs/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php on line 17093
```

I tried the solutions mentioned at [Upgrade to PHP7.1 and MPDF show error - A non-numeric value encountered at line 30648](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43994365/upgrade-to-php7-1-and-mpdf-show-error-a-non-numeric-value-encountered-at-line) but that hasn't fixed it.

Answer (score 19):

Edit mpdf.php, line 89, replace:

```
$errorlevel = error_reporting($errorlevel & ~E_NOTICE);
```

with:

```
$errorlevel = error_reporting($errorlevel & ~(E_NOTICE|E_WARNING));
```

Reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42044413/8284401