# Laravel/mPDF non-numeric value encountered ErrorException after PHP upgrade to 7.2

Tags: laravel, mpdf, php-7.2

I update php7.1 to php7.2.1 (PHP 7.2.1 (cli)) my laravel pdf not generated show below errorr:

```
(1/1) ErrorException

A non-numeric value encountered
in mpdf.php (line 30648)

at HandleExceptions->handleError(
    2, 
    'A non-numeric value encountered', 
    '/opt/lampp/htdocs/mysite/vendor/mpdf/mpdf/mpdf.php', 
    30648, 
    array(
        'size' => 0, 
        'maxsize' => 190.00155555555551245561218820512294769287109375, 
        'fontsize' => 3.704166666666667051543981870054267346858978271484375,
        'usefontsize' => false)
    )
in mpdf.php (line 30648)
```

[image]

Comment: re run: `composer require mpdf/mpdf` & then `composer update`

Comment: i got solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45101160/how-to-make-mpdf-6-1-work-with-php-7-1-5    Edit mpdf.php, line 89, replace:

$errorlevel = error_reporting($errorlevel & ~E_NOTICE);
with:

$errorlevel = error_reporting($errorlevel & ~(E_NOTICE|E_WARNING));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the error message, you are using mPDF 6.x which is not compatible with PHP 7.2 (and not entirely with PHP 7.1 for that matter).

You should [upgrade to mPDF 7](https://mpdf.github.io/installation-setup/installation-v7-x.html#upgrading-from-older-mpdf-versions) which is officially supported up to PHP 7.2.